# Nontrivial homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

Why is there no nontrivial homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$?

I have no idea of how to approach this problem, I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Comment: Note $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: I know but I can't see where that leads to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and the two factors are coprime, we get
$$
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-1)
\cong
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1)
\times
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)
$$
Composing with the projection onto the second factor gives the desired homomorphism.

Actually, this holds more generally. If $g(x)$ divides $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $$h(x) \bmod (f(x)) \mapsto h(x) \bmod (g(x))$$ is a well-defined homomorphism  $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x)) \to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(g(x))$.